# How to run a private Docker image

Tags: docker

```
docker run -i -t testing bash
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I created the image in Docker Hub , it is private image.

```
FROM scratch
# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR Desktop
ADD . /Dockerfile
RUN ./Dockerfile

EXPOSE 8085

ENV NAME testing
```

This is in my Dockerfile

I tired to run it, when i run docker images i am getting the details

Comment: This means that bash is not installed - try `sh` instead.

Comment: @halfer there is nothing in the scratch image even no `sh`.

Comment: Good spot @Adiii `:-)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do login in command prompt.useing below command.

```
docker login -u username -p password  url
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the login which should not cause these, as you build an image on your local system which I assume it should exist on local system which will only pull image if not exist on local, the real reason is you are building an image from **scratch** and there are no binaries in **scratch** image, even no **bash or sh**.

Second mistake:

```
RUN ./Dockerfile
```

Your Dockerfile is a file, not binaries, while here you are trying to execute using RUN directive.

While scratch appears in Docker’s repository on the hub, you can’t
pull it, run it, or tag any image with the name scratch. Instead, you
can refer to it in your Dockerfile. For example, to create a minimal
container using scratch:

```
FROM scratch
COPY hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

While here **hello** can be an executable file such as a C++ compiled file.

[Docker scratch image](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch)

But what I would suggest to say "hello" in Docker is to use [Busybox](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox/) or [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) as a base image which has a shell and both are under **5MB**.

```
FROM busybox
CMD ["echo","hello Docker!"]
```

now build and run

```
docker build -t hello-docker .
docker run --rm -it hello-docker
```